# Expand/collapse rows in a datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

One of the requirements that we have is to make a datatable(or something that looks very similar) with expanding rows.

An example would be:

Year 199x, I have a video collection of VHS and I want to keep the info about them in a table. Given the limited space of a screen, I will only show some important info on each row(for example: title, year, genre) and when I click on a row, I want the row to expand to show more info(for example: description, budget, box office, cast, to whom and when did I lend it, etc.).

What I have so far is not much, only a datatable:

```
<aura:attribute name="vhsList" type="VHS__c[]" />
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<lightning:datatable
            keyField="id"
            data="{! v.vhsList }"
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

Controller:

```
doInit : function (cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title__c', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Year', fieldName: 'Year__c', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Genre', fieldName: 'Genre__c', type: 'text'}
    ]);
    // And vhsList fill of course
}
```

I was thinking about using divs that become visible on a row click, but it does not seem possible with a datatable.

Is there a way to achieve expanding rows in a `lightning:datatable` or anything visually similar?

Comment: Do you really want to use expanding rows to visualize this? What about using a row action to open a modal showing these details using lightning:overlayLibrary?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new `<lightning:treeGrid>` component. This allows you to hide and show rows. I don't think `<lightning:datatable>` supports this functionality.

Here is the link to the [tree grid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/example) component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the treeGrid seems to preserve the original columns, but I only need a `div` or just a row where I can put whatever I like

Comment: Ok. May be `lightning:accordion` may fit your requirement? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:accordion/example This one you will have to customise with some html / css though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot achieve this with the base `lightning:datatable` as it only displays basic cell types.

You could create a custom table component starting from the [SLDS blueprint](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/) but it's a lot of work.

My recommendation in terms of UI is to have a side bar that gets populated with the selected row details.

```
+-------------+----------+
|             |          |
|             | Selected |
|  Datatable  | Row      |
|             | Details  |
|             |          |
+-------------+----------+
```

You can achieve this with a `lightning:layout` and `lightning:layoutItem` and you can make this collapsible when there is no selection.